# jQuery UI resizable bug on Chrome OSX

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/4saz84m8/1/)

On Chrome OSX if we adding jQuery UI resizeable to element with CSS attributes

```
.element{
   position: fixed;
   right: 0
}
```

after starting resize element goes to left. We found that problem only on Chrome OSX.

Any idea how to fix it? Is this a UI bug?